# Is there any way to send chrome history logs to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to send my google chrome history to kafka.

My basic idea is to use my local data located in

C:/Users/master/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/history

To do so, I want to use Kafka file source connector.

But how can I send newly added chrome history log after I run kakfa source connector?

Is there any way track the change of source file so kafka broker can acknowledge it?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use [FileStreamSourceConnector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/filestream_connector.html#filesource-connector) to achieve that. You do not need to anything else.

Once you start `FileStreamSourceConnector`, it will hook to the specified file. So, whenever new data is appended to the file, your connector will automatically produce to the topic.

From the link that I shared above:

> This connector will read only one file and send the data within that file to Kafka. It will then watch the file for appended updates only. Any modification of file lines already sent to Kafka will not be reprocessed.

This may help you: [Read File Data with Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/quickstart.html#read-file-data-with-kconnect)

Comment: thanks for your advice!!! I'll try it and let you know it worked, or I got another problem

Comment: This only reads single lines of plaintext, which I dont think Chrome history files are. This also doesn't track offsets of the file